# Tuple of Tuple to Dict of Dict with Dict Comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is it possible to convert a tuple of tuples like this:

```
l = (("a","aa",1),("a","bb",2),("a","cc",1),("b","ee",9),("b","gg",2))
```

to a dict of dicts like this:

```
{"a":{"aa":1,"bb":2,"cc":1}  "b": {"ee":9,"gg":2}}
```

using a dict comprehension like this:

```
r = {? for a,b,c in l}
```

Comment: Personally, I would argue it’s better to use a for loop and a few more lines to ease readability and complexity.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) with a dictionary comprehension:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

l = (("a", "aa", 1), ("a", "bb", 2), ("a", "cc", 1), ("b", "ee", 9), ("b", "gg", 2))

first = itemgetter(0)
result = {key: {inner: value for _, inner, value in groups} for key, groups in groupby(l, key=first)}

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
{'b': {'gg': 2, 'ee': 9}, 'a': {'cc': 1, 'bb': 2, 'aa': 1}}
```

As mentioned by @juanpa.arrivillaga if the input is not sorted by the first element of each tuple, you need to sort it, for that you can do: `l = sorted(l, key=first)` before using the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: You will have to sort first

Answer (score 3):

Use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
from itertools import groupby

l = (("a","aa",1),("a","bb",2),("a","cc",1),("b","ee",9),("b","gg",2))

print({x: {z[1]: z[2] for z in y} for x, y in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])})
# {'a': {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 1}, 'b': {'ee': 9, 'gg': 2}}
```

Comment: You need to sort first

Comment: @aws_apprentice, Missed that `key` can come anywhere in list. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, Daniel Mesejo's answer nailed it.  That answer is based on `groupby`, but functionally speaking, `groupby` is a form of `reduce`.   So, for variety, I'll offer here a solution with `functools.reduce` (which also uses `defaultdict`):

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> l = (("a","aa",1),("a","bb",2),("a","cc",1),("b","ee",9),("b","gg",2))
>>> def update_and_return(acc, up):
...     acc[up[0]][up[1]] = up[2]
...     return acc
... 
>>> reduce(update_and_return, l, defaultdict(dict))
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'a': {'aa': 1, 'cc': 1, 'bb': 2}, 'b': {'ee': 9, 'gg': 2}})
```

Even though this isn't a dictionary comprehension solution, I hope it will provide more context for someone wanting to understand the computation required to answer the question.

Comment: juanpa.arrivillaga: thanks, edited as per your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Do you enjoy abusing `built-ins` for not their intended purpose? I would honestly use the other answers here but this is also another way to do this.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

any(d[x[0]].update({x[1]: x[-1]}) for x in l)

print(d)

defaultdict(dict, {'a': {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 1}, 'b': {'ee': 9, 'gg': 2}})
```

Using `any` will return a `boolean` which clearly is not the intended purpose here hence why I recommend other answers listed.

Answer (score 0):

here is what I would probably use, because I feel it is fairly readable...

```
l = (("a","aa",1),("a","bb",2),("a","cc",1),("b","ee",9),("b","gg",2))
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

for a,b,c in l:
    d[a][b]=c


print(d)

defaultdict(dict, {'a': {'aa': 1, 'bb': 2, 'cc': 1}, 'b': {'ee': 9, 'gg': 2}})
```

I did a crude benchmark against the other solution I like (groupby):

```
l = (("a","aa",1),("a","bb",2),("a","cc",1),("b","ee",9),("b","gg",2))
from collections import defaultdict
def dd():
    d = defaultdict(dict)
    for a,b,c in l:
        d[a][b]=c


def gb():
    {x: {z[1]: z[2] for z in y} for x, y in groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x: x[0]), lambda x: x[0])}

def gb2():
    first = itemgetter(0)
    result = {key: {inner: value for _, inner, value in groups} for key, groups in groupby(l, key=first)}

%timeit dd()
%timeit gb()
%timeit gb2()

683 ns ± 1.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
2.11 µs ± 129 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
1.38 µs ± 29.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

(you see the added value of itemgetter vs having to do another import, also groupby expects a sorted input so for larger lists the performance penalty should be even worse...)